# How to refocus where it was in textfield after pressing a button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

There is a javascript button that if it's pressed, it inserts a string.
Then after pressing a button, focus will back to textfield.
However, with my code, always focus goes back to end of the string, not where it was.

For example now focus is between 3 and 4.

[image]

and after pressing "ā", focus goes to after 7.

[image]

But I want the focus go to between "ā" and 4.

Here is my code

```
<script>
function addTF(str)
{
    var area = document.getElementById('pronounce');
    area.value = area.value.substr(0, area.selectionStart)
    + str
    + area.value.substr(area.selectionStart);
    area.focus();
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="pronounce" name="pronounce">
<input type="button" value="ā" onClick="addTF(this.value)">
```

So how can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` of the text field to restore the previous caret position:

```js
var addTF;

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    var area = document.getElementById('pronounce');
    var lastPos = 0;
    
    area.addEventListener('change', () => lastPos = area.selectionStart);
    area.addEventListener('click', () => lastPos = area.selectionStart);

    addTF = function(str) {
        area.value = area.value.substr(0, area.selectionStart) + str + area.value.substr(area.selectionStart);
        lastPos++;
        area.selectionStart = lastPos;
        area.selectionEnd = lastPos;
        area.focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="pronounce" name="pronounce">
<input type="button" value="ā" onClick="addTF(this.value)">
```

Comment: Yes, your code works properly on html. but if I write on my php laravel, button stop working. I will check what is wrong.

Comment: Probably because of your code runs before the page is loaded. Check my updated answer. Or you can put the `<script>` block at the end of the html before `</body>`